# Kendo UI Load Complete event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Is there any event to know that Kendo UI is done loading my control, some `Load_Complete` type of event? The problem is if we declare our control like this:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" id="dt" />

<script>

$("#dt").kendoDatePicker({
 animation: {
   close: {
            effects: "fadeOut zoom:out",
            duration: 300
          },
   open: {
            effects: "fadeIn zoom:in",
            duration: 300
          }
   },
 ARIATemplate: "Date: #=kendo.toString(data.current, 'G')#",
 culture: "en-US",
 format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
 parseFormats: "MM/dd/yyyy"
});

</script>
```

Then there's no way to know that this input box is a Kendo UI datepicker at the time of document ready because till that time Kendo is not done transforming control into a datepicker. An event which can tell me that Kendo UI has done it's work then I can easily find control and do whatever needs to be done with them.

Note: requirement is of a global/common solution. This particular case, shown as sample, can be solved easily if I place my script after Kendo UI initialization, but need is of a solution which can allow us to write the script anywhere like in an external .js file.

Comment: Well, not sure what you exactly need but: a) you can try `$("#dt").data('kendoDatePicker')`. It will be returned as undefined if control is not kendo control. So you can write something like `if($("#dt").data('kendoDatePicker')) { //kendo date picker exists } else {// kendo date picker not exists}` ... b) There is dataBound event which is fired after kendo control is initialized. You can call function doing next steps.

Comment: @Ademar all Kendo widgets doesn't posses dataBound event, like for example date picker which is in OP, do not have dataBound event :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if (kendo)
{
//do something
}
```

OR

```
if (typeof kendo != 'undefined') {
  // do something
}
```

should work

Comment: It just tells whether Kendo UI framework is loaded or not, What I want is to know whether Kendo UI is done formatting my controls or not.

Comment: @yogi my bad. I misunderstood the question. I'm going to update my answer.